# How do I address .ui-dialog properties?

Tags: jquery, css

I am using jquery-ui-1.10.4 and doing a css override on a themed property like so:

```
.ui-dialog {
  left: 0;
  outline: 0 none;
  padding: 10px !important;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; }
```

Now, occasionally, I want to change the padding from inside a JavaScript function using a jQuery call to a dialog like so:

```
 function myFunction ()
 {
   …
   $('#myDialog').dialog ({…});

   $(".ui-dialog").css({ "padding" : "0" }); // not working
  }
```

As stated, this is not working, whereas it does when I change the value for padding from within the Inspector.

How should I do it from inside the JS code?

N.B.: I have also tried to add the *!important* attribute to the padding value —to no avail.

Comment: I've updated my answer, since you said adding `!important` did not help.

Answer (score 1):

Your "problem" is that you're already overwriting the property with `!important`, so you need to tell your new property that it's at least as important as the current modification.

Try this:

```
$(".ui-dialog").css({ "padding" : "0 !important" });
```

**Edit:**

What about adding a new CSS class:

```
.no-padding,
.ui-dialog.no-padding /* this helps us to be even more precise, giving this a higher priority */ {
    padding: 0 !important;
}
```

and instead of overwriting the padding, you add the class to your element:

```
$(".ui-dialog").addClass("no-padding");
```